# Symbol error while creating a package SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, package

My goal here is to create a package for a sql function that I created.
I'm using the EMP and DEPT tables (https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_O5AEB2HE08PYEPTGCFLZU9YCV.html)

Here's the function (that works) :

```
create or replace function PRENOM_EMP (nom in EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%type)
return EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type
is prenom EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type;
begin
    select FIRST_NAME
    into prenom
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE last_name = nom;
return prenom;

EXCEPTION
    when too_many_rows then
    return ('l ordre sql ramene plus d une ligne');

end;

Select PRENOM_EMP ('King') from dual; /* Example of use */
```

This is how I try to put this function in a package :

```
create or replace package PKG_EMPLOYES as

function PRENOM_EMP (nom in EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%type)
    return EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type IS
    prenom EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type;
begin
    select FIRST_NAME
    into prenom
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE last_name = nom;
return prenom;

EXCEPTION
    when too_many_rows then
    return ('l ordre sql ramene plus d une ligne');

end PRENOM_EMP;

end PKG_EMPLOYES;
```

the error occurs at the 5th line

```
prenom EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type;
```

and SQL developer says : "Erreur(34,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PRENOM" when expecting one of the following:     language "

I followed the example of how to use packages from this website (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6006.htm) but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break it into a package spec and package body.

So..

Spec:

```
create or replace package PKG_EMPLOYES as

function PRENOM_EMP (nom in EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%type)
    return EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type;

end PKG_EMPLOYES;
/
```

And body:

```
create or replace package body PKG_EMPLOYES as

function PRENOM_EMP (nom in EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%type)
    return EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type IS
    prenom EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type;
begin
    select FIRST_NAME
    into prenom
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE last_name = nom;
return prenom;

EXCEPTION
    when too_many_rows then
    return ('l ordre sql ramene plus d une ligne');

end PRENOM_EMP;

end PKG_EMPLOYES;
/
```

Comment: so you create the spec then the body?
btw, thanks for the quick answer, it works

Comment: Yeah the spec is what's visible to others. The guts are not so there could be private function in there which would never be callable from outside the package.

Comment: one last thing, on the website, it says that to use a function in the package, I need to do PACK_NAME.FUNCT_NAME('...'). if I do that in a new sql sheet, it says unknown command. how / where should I call it?

Comment: don't worry, I found the answer, I need to do some pl/sql to use packages